# How to use NowJS to provide notifications to user in django framework

Tags: django, node.js, notifications, long-polling, nowjs-sockets

I have built a website in django framework. It has a lot of features such as blog, discussion forum, basically there are lots of ways users can interact. I have built a basic notification framework where a user gets notified when somebody comments on their blog, or answers their question in the forum.

Since the notifications are stored in db, new notifications are displayed only when a page refresh is done. I would like to make it real time using some push server using something like long polling technique.

I have come across `NowJS` which seems to be pretty handy for this, but in all the examples that are given I could not see any example where there was any interaction with the database. In all the cases there was some information sent by one client and it was displayed to one or more clients.

What I actually want to do is to call a function using NowJS, and make it go to sleep until a new notification is added in the database. When a new notifications comes in the server responds back with the notification and a new request is done immediately.

I can figure out all other parts except how to access the database from Node server that is used by NowJS. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Have your node.js server make an http call to the Django server via something like a REST api to get info back
2. Google for a database connector for node.js - I found enough evidence for a MySQL one, and rumours of a PostgreSQL one. Note this won't get you access to the Django DB API, so you'll have to work out all your related queries and craft your SQL by hand (make sure Bobby Tables doesn't bother you: http://www.xkcd.com/327)
3. Re-implement the NowJS protocol so that you can write a django server for it, keeping the same JS client code on the clients... but then you may as wel.....

...use django-socketio http://blog.jupo.org/2011/08/13/real-time-web-apps-with-django-and-websockets/

Comment: Can't I use something like RabbitMQ that would allow me to push data into a stream from django and that will be read by the Node.js server??? Re-implementing the NowJS protocol will be not feasible because I need to work on some other things as well, and redevelopment can take too much time

Comment: That's kinda like the inverse of (1) - have Django make an http call to the Node.js server. I guess your flow is: user POSTs new message to forum via django; django server sends http request to Node.js server; Node.js redistributes to listeners. Its like the classic NowJS chatroom example except the Django server is talking, and browsers are listening. You probably don't need a message queue like RabbitMQ in the way.

Comment: yes I am getting your point but then again I am unable to figure out how can django serevr send http request to Node.js. I have come across this article that uses RabbitMQ to put the data onto a message queue and Node.js is listening to these queues. could you point me in the correct direction

Comment: Django is python. Python can send http requests using urllib2 and friends.